# What is wrong with my React Native Reanimated colour interpolation animation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I'm trying to do something extremely simple - have my button be transparent while not pressed, and change its background color to a different colour gradually when a user presses it. To achieve that, I'm using React Native Reanimated. Unfortunately, there's something wrong with my animation and I'm not sure what. The issue is this:

I change isPressed to true when the button is pressed and to false when the user moves his finger away from the button. Then I use that isPressed boolean to change the progress and finally use that progress to interpolate the colour from transparent to my other colour. Sadly what happens is this:

I press on the button and instead of the button changing its background color almost instantly, it takes like 5 seconds before turning to colors.primary50. Then if I unpress the button, it takes another 5 or so seconds to turn back to transparent. Also I don't really see gradual change in color, it just changes instantly.

```
const TertiaryButton: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ title, wide = false, style, ...rest }) => {
    const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);

    const progress = useSharedValue(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        progress.value = withTiming(isPressed ? 1 : 0, { easing: Easing.out(Easing.cubic), duration: 1000 });
    }, [isPressed, progress]);

    const rStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        const backgroundColor = interpolateColor(progress.value, [0, 1], ['transparent', colors.primary50]);

        return { backgroundColor };
    });

    return (
        <Pressable onPressIn={() => setIsPressed(true)} onPressOut={() => setIsPressed(false)} {...rest}>
            <Button
                wide={wide}
                style={[
                    style,
                    {
                        ...rStyle,
                    },
                ]}
            >
                <ButtonText variant="h4">{title}</ButtonText>
            </Button>
        </Pressable>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the progress value instantly inside `onPressIn` and `onPressOut`.

```
onPressOut={() => {
  console.log("onPressOut")
  isPressed.value = withTiming(0)
}}

onPressIn={() => {
  console.log("onPressIn")
  isPressed.value = withTiming(1)
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible reason for this not working is that the `Button` component may not be an Animated component. You need to make sure that `Button` is an animated component. If it's a custom/library component, you can wrap it with `Animated.createAnimatedComponent(...)` to make it an Animated component:

```js
const AnimatedButton = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Button);
```